# How to update values in table with this.state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make a component, which show information from database in table. But this information with filters. 
Filtering can be by *event type* and by *participant* (id: integer type).

When I click the button, I call **handleShowClick()**. In this function I check: if value of *type event* isn't null, I get from database *events* with this type. if value of *type event* is null, I get all *events*.

After this I check a *participant* value. If value isn't null, I call function, which search which *events* are include this *participant*. Data from **this.state.event show** in table in another component.

I haven't problems with *event type*. But I have problem with *participant*. When I choose one of *participant*, table shows correct data for a split second. After this return to prev state (without filter by participants).

How can I fix this issue? I set state to **event** only in this component

```
class TestPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      event: [],
      searchByType: null,
      searchByParticipant: null,
      participantToEvent: []
    };
    this.handleShowClick = this.handleShowClick.bind(this);
    this.onHandleEventByTypeFetch = this.onHandleEventByTypeFetch.bind(this);
    this.handleParticipantSearch = this.handleParticipantSearch.bind(this);
    this.onHandleEventFetch = this.onHandleEventFetch.bind(this);
  }

  handleShowClick() {  // onClick
      if (this.state.searchByType !== null) {
        this.onHandleEventByTypeFetch();  // select * from ... where type=...
      } else {
        this.onHandleEventFetch(); // select * from ...
      }
      if (this.state.searchByParticipant !== null) {
        this.handleParticipantSearch();
      }
  }

  handleParticipantSearch() {
    const list = [];

    this.state.participantToEvent.map(itemP => {  // participantToEvent is binding table
      if (itemP.parid === this.state.searchByParticipant) {
        this.state.event.map(itemEvent => {
          if (itemEvent.id === itemP.eventid) {
            list.push(itemEvent);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(list);  // here I see array with correct result
    this.setState({ event: list });
  }

  onHandleEventFetch() {
    fetch( ... , {
      method: 'GET'
    })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error('Bad response from server');
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          if (data.length === 0) {
            alert('nothing');
          } else {
            this.setState({
              event: data
            });
          }
        });
  }

  onHandleEventByTypeFetch() {
    fetch( ... , {
      method: 'GET'
    })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error('Bad response from server');
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          if (data.length === 0) {
            alert('nothing');
          } else {
            this.setState({
              event: data
            });
          }
        });
    ...
  }
}
```

Structure of this.state.event:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'New event', participant: 5, type: 10}, ...]
```

Structure of this.state.participantToEvent:

```
[{id: 1, idparticipant: 5, idevent: 1}, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState(...this.state,{ event: list });
```

I think this would solve your problem. Because you clear every item except for {event:list} by not copying the previous state.

Edit:

You should put

```
...this.state
```

to `onHandleEventByeTypeFetch` and `onHandleEventFetch`. Without them when you click `handleShowClick` one of those two functions always work and clears `searchByParticipant` data from the state by not copying the previous state.

The reason for you see the correct data for a short time is all about async nature of the state.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't help for me

Comment: Add this.setState(...this.state, ... to all functions, but it isn't help me